# How to cast IEnumerable<dynamic> to IDictionary<,>?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dictionary

I have this data from data entities contained in IEnumerable model

```
Address: "test"
AuctioneerId: 0
CharityId: 0
City: "test"
```

i want to put that in `IDictionary<string. object>` to get the title Address and value test.

[image]

Comment: `dynamic` is not a type. It's a way to  look at underlying, real type in dynamic way. What kind of data your `IEnumerable<dynamic>` really holds?

Comment: this is the full code view http://clip2net.com/s/745aDz

Comment: hmm, looks like you're trying to get entity properties into Dictionary, with property name as key and property value as value. It has nothing to do with `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Looks like really bad design and is probably XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/208082

Comment: the reason I'm doing that is i'm creating an export to csv using streamwriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have class like this one:

```
class Test
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

And an instance of `Test`.

```
var item = new Test { Value1 = 1, Value2 = "hey!!!" };
```

To get `Dictionary<string, object>` with property names as keys and values as values you can either use reflection:

```
var dict = item.GetType()
               .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty)
               .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(item));
```

or add a method to `Test` and create dictionary manually:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        { "Value1", Value1 },
        { "Value2", Value2 }
    };
}
```

and use it:

```
var dict = item.ToDictionary();
```

Second one will perform better, but you have to write all properties manually into dictionary. But actually that might be a good thing, if you only want a subset of values be present in result dictionary.